# How to drive the Form events in a other class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I desire the following:

When clickee a button on the form, I want to handle the events are another class. Thus, the form contains only controls.

It's almost like a MVC pattern: Controller I have a class, and a class RegistrarTrabajador (Model). When controller detects an event of the form, passes the task to the model.

Here the Controller class and the form:

Controller:

```
namespace RegistroDeUsuarios
{
    public class Controller 
    {
        private MainWindow vista;
        private RegistrarTrabajador modelo;

       public Controller()
        {

        }

        public Controller(MainWindow vista, RegistrarTrabajador modelo)
        {
            this.vista = vista;
            this.modelo = modelo;          
        }

       public void btnRegistrar_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           Trabajador trabajador = new Trabajador();
           trabajador.setPrimerNombre(vista.txtPrimerNombre.Text);
           trabajador.setSegundoNombre(vista.txtSegundoNombre.Text);
           trabajador.setPrimerApellido(vista.txtPrimerApellido.Text);
           trabajador.setSegundoApellido(vista.txtSegundoApellido.Text);
           trabajador.setRangoTrabajador(vista.cboRangoTrabajador.SelectedItem.ToString());
           trabajador.setFechaNacimiento(vista.txtFechaNacimiento.Text);
           modelo.registrarTrabajador(trabajador);
       }

       public void btnNuevo_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           vista.clean();
       }

       public void btnSalir_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           //Application.Current.Shutdown();
       }
    }
}
```

GUI:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cboRangoTrabajador.Items.Add("Administrador");
        cboRangoTrabajador.Items.Add("Vendedor");
        cboRangoTrabajador.Items.Add("Contador");
        cboRangoTrabajador.Items.Add("Tecnico Mantenimiento");
        cboRangoTrabajador.Items.Add("Programador");
        cboRangoTrabajador.Items.Add("Analista");
        cboRangoTrabajador.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    public void setControlador(Controller controlador)
    {
        controlador.btnRegistrar_Click(controlador,new RoutedEventArgs());
        controlador.btnNuevo_Click(controlador,new RoutedEventArgs());
        controlador.btnSalir_Click(controlador,new RoutedEventArgs());
    }

    public void clean()
    {
        txtPrimerNombre.Clear();
        txtSegundoNombre.Clear();
        txtPrimerApellido.Clear();
        txtSegundoApellido.Clear();
        txtFechaNacimiento.Clear();
        cboRangoTrabajador.SelectedItem = "Administrador";
        txtPrimerNombre.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Discussion suggests it is unneeded to put tags in the title. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use MVC in WPF. You use [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

And

you don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. 
Please read about [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx),

things like this:

```
trabajador.setPrimerNombre(vista.txtPrimerNombre.Text);
trabajador.setSegundoNombre(vista.txtSegundoNombre.Text);
```

are horrible and should NEVER be done in WPF.

---

Also, your code smells like crappy java. Instead of methods like `setPrimerNombre()` you should really use [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). WPF has support for two way databinding to properties, so you don't need to do all this piping manually.

---

To make this clear, here is a small example:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.LastName}"/>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Model.FirstName}"/>
  <Button Content="Registrar" Click="Registrar_Click"/>
  <Button Content="Clear" Click="Clear_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
public class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get { return DataContext as MainViewModel; } }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }

    public void Registrar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Registrar();
    }

    public void Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Clear();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel: ViewModelBase //You should have some ViewModelBase implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, etc
{
    private Trabajador _model;
    public Trabajador Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set
        {
           _model = value;
           NotifyPropertyChange("Model");
        }
    }

    public void Registrar()
    {
       DataAccessLayer.Registrar(Model);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
       Model = new Trabajador();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Trabajador: ModelBase //ModelBase Should also implement INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    //... And so on.
}
```

Comment: Will I get flamed for asking if there is a *non-crappy* Java?

Comment: @dwerner no, a non-crappy java actually exists, it's called `C#`.

Comment: Yes, im Java programmer, and it's my first "app" in C# and i didnt never know about MVVM. Im sorry for my "crappy java code" xD.

Sorry for my english..

Comment: @user2909121 it's not that YOUR code is bad, it's `java` in itself which is really horrible.

Comment: @HighCore while many of the founding ideas in C# come from Java, I still think it's a bit insulting... to C#.

Comment: @dwerner You know, there was this bald guy with a gray long beard, who had these crazy ideas about something called `Evolution`. I don't really care if java came first, my 12 MHZ 386 machine also came before the Intel Core I7 based computers, and probably there is a lot in the I7 that was based off of the x86 era. That's no reason to stick to dinosaur stuff and refuse to grow up and evolve, just like java.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to have fully understand what you mean but i think you want to know what it is the best way of building a WPF application in layers.

If that's right then MVVM pattern is definitly what you are looking for. [Here is a great link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) to understand how it works and to begin to play with it!